# input from php form not populating value in other page

Tags: php

I have read multiple questions posted and am unable to locate one that directly answers what I am trying to accomplish.  I have tried several suggestions in other posting answers but still have not the results I am seeking.

I am trying to get input to populate on my sample page (single2.php) from single_name form.

Here is the code on single_name.php:

```
<form name="singlename" method="post" action="./single2.php" id="Form1" onsubmit="return Validatesinglename(this)">
<div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:15px;width:81px;height:16px;z-index:0;text-align:left;"><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Name:</span></div><input type="text" id="name" style="position:absolute;left:101px;top:15px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:1;" name="name" value="" autocomplete="off">
<div id="wb_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:45px;width:81px;height:16px;z-index:2;text-align:left;"><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Gender:</span></div><input type="text" id="gender" style="position:absolute;left:101px;top:45px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:25;" name="Gender" value="">
<div id="wb_Text3" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:75px;width:81px;height:16px;z-index:4;text-align:left;"><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Date of Birth:</span></div><input type="date" id="dob" style="position:absolute;left:101px;top:75px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:5;" name="dob:" value="" autocomplete="off">
<div id="wb_Text4" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:105px;width:81px;height:16px;z-index:6;text-align:left;"><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Message:</span></div><input type="text" id="message" style="position:absolute;left:101px;top:105px;width:198px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:7;" name="Message:" value="" autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Send" style="position:absolute;left:101px;top:135px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:8;">
<input type="reset" id="Button2" name="" value="Reset" style="position:absolute;left:207px;top:136px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:9;">
</form>
```

and here is what is on single2.php:

```
<div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:428px;top:514px;width:515px;height:391px;text-align:center;z-index:29;">
   echo $_POST["name"]; 
}
?></strong></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Chancellor;font-size:19px;">
<br>
<br>
Local Origin of Name:&nbsp; Unique and Original<br>From the name
<?php
{
   echo $_POST["name"]; 
}    <br>
<br>
Evaluation Meaning:&nbsp; Festive, Joyous
<br>
<br>
<strong>&#0042;</strong> Emotional Spectrum <strong>&#0042;</strong>
<br>
Up front and honest
<br>
<strong>&#0042;</strong> Personal Integrity <strong>&#0042;</strong>
<br>
Friends know that
<?php
{
   echo $_POST["name"]; 
?>
can be called on in a crisis.
<br>
<strong>&#0042;</strong> Personality <strong>&#0042;</strong>
<br>
Life in the fast lane, tempered by common sense.
<br>
<strong>&#0042;</strong>&nbsp; Relationships <strong>&#0042;</strong>
<br>
Stays true and loyal
<br>
<br>
```

```
<?php
{
   echo $_POST["name"]; 
}
?>    is a 
<?php
{
   echo $_POST["gender"]; 
}
?>
<br>
<br>
{
   echo $_POST["name"]; 
}
?>
was born 
<?php
{
   echo $_POST["dob"]; 
}
?>
<br>
<br>
</span>
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Georgia;font-size:27px;"><strong><em>
<?php
{
   echo $_POST["message"]; 
}
?></em></strong>
</span>
```

I can get the "name" to post at each place, but the "gender", "dob" and "message" does not post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with external styling? `[CSS]` ?

Comment: Please, please for the sake of those of us with eyes move to using external style sheets.

Comment: What is external style sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled your names wrong on single_name.php

```
name="Gender"
name="dob:"
name="Message:"
```

You **must** use the same names (lowercase without colon)

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly.  I have changed that in my single_name.php.  But now that I have made the changes, when I run my page, single2.php, which I did not make any changes to, gives an error message.

Comment: Can you see what the error is in the error_log file? This may be becuase you forgot "<?php" before printing the name in "{name} was born {dob}"

Comment: The error is when I launch in browser (I am using WebMatrix), I can go through the form, but when I click submit, this is what I get:

Comment: The website cannot display the page

Comment: Friends know that
<?php
{
   echo $_POST["name"]; 
?> missing "}" maybe..? make sure to close all blocks {} and <?php ?> statements.. there are a few of these in single2.php

Comment: but I did nothing to that page.  That is what is frustrating me.  I get one thing fixed and something else goes wrong

Comment: Don't get frustrated.. :) single2.php as originally posted in the question has these issues. fix them and try again.

Comment: Walked away and came back, used eaton9999's code for single2.php and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
 name="name"
 name="Gender" 
 name="dob:"
 name="Message:"
```

So, post should be of the same case

```
$_POST['name']
$_POST['Gender']
$_POST['dob:']
$_POST['Message:']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="Gender" >#name should be 'gender' not 'Gender'
<input name="dob:" >#name should be 'dob' not 'dob:'
<input name="Message:" >#name should be 'message' not be 'Message:'
```

for future the name of your input `name` should match up with your post value as well as being case sensitive so 'Gender' !== 'gender' and so forth

Answer (score 0):

Your names do not match as stated. Easy way to see what is coming across is to add a debug tag in your Single_2.php page of :
print_r($_POST);
this will "mess up your page" while used but will allow you to see the entire $_POST array with keys and data that is coming across. Then you can check names etc.

To see the array in a more readable format right mouse click and "inspect element"

Comment: Where would you add the pring_r($_POST) script?

Comment: I would add it basically anywhere -but the top of the page would suffice typically. Remember this is only for debug. If you add it to the very bottom then you will see your "normal" output and then appended by the array. the code is:
print_r($_POST);

Comment: BTW: Share your error log or other web page using http://jsfiddle.net/
Drop in the code, run it and save, then share the link on this site.

Comment: There were several issues mostly relating to variable names and turning php on and off - See new answer

Answer (score 0):

try to insert such debug code and see what keys are stored in your POST array:

```
echo '<pre>'
var_dump($_POST);
```

And also try not to use special symbols in your input names, because this example will not work proprely:

```
$_POST['dob:'] = 'somevalue';

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cut and paste the following corrected code into your application. It has been tested and works fine.

## "single_name.php" is as follows:

---

```
<form id="Form1" action="./single2.php" method="post" name="singlename" onsubmit="return Validatesinglename(this)">

<div id="wb_Text1" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 15px; width: 81px; height: 16px; z-index: 0; text-align: left;">
    <span style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px;">Name:</span></div>
<input id="name" autocomplete="off" name="name" style="position: absolute; left: 101px; top: 15px; width: 198px; height: 23px; line-height: 23px; z-index: 1;" type="text" value="">

<div id="wb_Text2" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 45px; width: 81px; height: 16px; z-index: 2; text-align: left;">
    <span style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px;">Gender:</span></div>
<input id="gender" name="gender" style="position: absolute; left: 101px; top: 45px; width: 198px; height: 23px; line-height: 23px; z-index: 25;" type="text" value="">

<div id="wb_Text3" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 75px; width: 81px; height: 16px; z-index: 4; text-align: left;">
    <span style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px;">Date 
    of Birth:</span></div>
<input id="dob" autocomplete="off" name="dob" style="position: absolute; left: 101px; top: 75px; width: 198px; height: 23px; line-height: 23px; z-index: 5;" type="date" value="">

<div id="wb_Text4" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 105px; width: 81px; height: 16px; z-index: 6; text-align: left;">
    <span style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px;">Message:</span></div>
<input id="message" autocomplete="off" name="message" style="position: absolute; left: 101px; top: 105px; width: 198px; height: 23px; line-height: 23px; z-index: 7;" type="text" value="">

<input id="Button1" name="" style="position: absolute; left: 101px; top: 135px; width: 96px; height: 25px; z-index: 8;" type="submit" value="Send">
<input id="Button2" name="" style="position: absolute; left: 207px; top: 136px; width: 96px; height: 25px; z-index: 9;" type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

### and "single2.php" is as follows:

```
<div id="wb_Text1" style="position: absolute; left: 428px; top: 514px; width: 515px; height: 391px; text-align: center; z-index: 29;">

<?php echo $_POST["name"];  ?>  
</strong></span><span style="color: #000000; font-family: Chancellor; font-size: 19px;">
<br><br>
Local Origin of Name:&nbsp; Unique and Original<br>From the name 
<?php echo $_POST["name"];?>
<br>
<br>
Evaluation Meaning:&nbsp; Festive, Joyous
<br>
<br>
<strong>&#0042;</strong> Emotional Spectrum <strong>&#0042;</strong>
<br>
Up front and honest
<br>
<strong>&#0042;</strong> Personal Integrity <strong>&#0042;</strong>
<br>
Friends know that 
<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> 
can be called on in a crisis. <br><strong>&#0042;</strong> Personality <strong>&#0042;</strong>
<br>Life in the fast lane, tempered by common sense. <br><strong>&#0042;</strong>&nbsp; 
Relationships <strong>&#0042;</strong> <br>Stays true and loyal <br><br>
</span></div>

<?php //following for debug
echo 'Name is : '.$_POST["name"].'<br>'; 
echo 'Gender is : '.$_POST["gender"].'<br>'; 
echo 'Date of Birth is : '.$_POST["dob"].'<br>'; 
echo 'Message is : '.$_POST["message"].'<br>'; 
?>
```

Comment: With a little rearranging, it is working perfectly.  Thank you!